# Арифметика в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Делаю простой калькулятор на bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    read arg1 op arg2
    if [[ "$arg1" -eq "exit" ]]
    then    
        break
    fi

    flag=0
    for ops in + - * / % **
    do
        if [[ "$op" = "$ops" ]]
        then
            flag=1
        fi  
    done 

    if [[ $flag = 1 ]]
    then
        let "result = $arg1 $op $arg2"
        echo "$result"
    else
        echo "error"
    fi


done

echo "bye"
```

Смысл в том, что на вход я подаю 3 значения, аргументы и операция между ними. Например, `12 + 5`.

Все хорошо работает, кроме операций `*` и `**`.

В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `for ops in + - * / % **`

заключите по крайней мере `*` и `**` в кавычки. а лучше — все аргументы:

```
for ops in '+' '-' '*' '/' '%' '**'
```

тогда оболчка не будет пытаться делать какие-либо подстановки.

Comment: А почему в одинарные ?

Comment: @faoxis, для надёжности.

Answer (score 3):

Или можно поставить экранирование

```
for ops in + - * / % **
```

вот так

```
for ops in + - \* / % \*\*
```